# NoClassDefFoundError or NoSuchMethodError when trying to mock static (incompatible dependencies)

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockito

When a class with static method is mocked, an exception been thrown. The version `2.0.0` of PowerMock displays `NoClassDefFoundError`<sup>1</sup>. The versions `2.0.1` and `2.0.2` displays `NoSuchMethodError`<sup>2</sup>.

In project that I work is used Mockito on version `2.25.0`, but I've tried using new versions of Mockito following the compatible versions table (https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions). In addition, I tested the downgrade to versions 2.8.9 of Mockito with 1.7.x of Powermock without success.

Would be a bug?

---

Test class:

```
import my.pack.ldap.LdapUtil;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(LdapUtil.class)
public class AuthenticationLdapTest {

    @Test
    public void mustAuthenticateWhenCredencialsIsValid() {
        mockStatic(LdapUtil.class);
    }
}
```

OBS: `LdapUtil` is a class of an internal artifact and depends on other classes of the package `org.springframework.ldap`.

Exception 1 (using version 2.0.0 of PowerMock):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/access/SingletonBeanFactoryLocator

    at my.pack.ldap.LdapUtil.<clinit>(LdapUtil.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor4.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:48)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.instance.ObjenesisInstantiator.newInstance(ObjenesisInstantiator.java:19)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:47)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:25)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.createMock(PowerMockMaker.java:41)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:62)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1907)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(DefaultMockCreator.java:108)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.doCreateMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:61)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:53)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.mock(DefaultMockCreator.java:40)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:62)
    at my.pack.system.ejb.authentication.AuthenticationLdapTest.mustAuthenticateWhenCredencialsIsValid(AuthenticationLdapTest.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:326)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadClassByThisClassLoader(MockClassLoader.java:100)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:147)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:98)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 49 more
```

Exception 2 (using version 2.0.[1-2] of PowerMock):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javassist.CtClass.getDeclaredClasses()[Ljavassist/CtClass;

    at org.powermock.core.transformers.javassist.ConstructorsMockTransformer.transform(ConstructorsMockTransformer.java:50)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.javassist.AbstractJavaAssistMockTransformer.transform(AbstractJavaAssistMockTransformer.java:40)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.support.DefaultMockTransformerChain.transform(DefaultMockTransformerChain.java:43)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.transformClass(MockClassLoader.java:184)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.javassist.JavassistMockClassLoader.defineAndTransformClass(JavassistMockClassLoader.java:102)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:174)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadClassByThisClassLoader(MockClassLoader.java:102)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:147)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:98)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:154)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:47)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:69)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:36)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
```

---

### Edit (Aug. 12, 2019)

Seems there are some incompatibility among dependencies of the project that I work. I've created a new POC (Proof of Concept) project using the versions mentioned above without any errors.

So, now I'd like to know how to discover what dependency is causing incompatibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Exception 2: 
I had a similar issue with Maven. Checked dependency tree (mvn depedency:tree) and found two conflicting versions of javassist. Once older version was excluded from pom issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, as Andrew said, it is the problem about conflicting between two version javassist.

Parent pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

And then add this to children pom, for removing parent dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>*</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```